# Rails Partials and Simple Form Answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm using Simple Form with my Rails 4 app.

I have a structure which has models for each of projects, scopes, and data.

Data belongs to scopes, scopes belong to projects.

I have just made a partial view for data which should be displayed in the projects show page if the answer to the question in the scopes form is true.

I have:

An if statement in my projects show view to ask if the answer to the question in project scope form is true, as follows:

```
<% if @project.scope.try(:data) == true %>
    <%= render 'data/particulars'%>
<% end %>
```

A question in my scope form for:

```
<%= f.input :data, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true  %>
```

A data/_particulars partial in the data folder of my views folder with:

```
<div class="containerfluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

  <div class="dataheading">Detail of the data requested</div>
    <div class="datasubtext"><%= @project.scope.try(:datum).try(:prim_sec) %>
      <%= @project.scope.try(:datum).try(:qual_quant) %>
    </div>
    <div class="datageneral">
      <%= @project.scope.try(:datum).try(:survey_link) %>
      <%= @project.scope.try(:datum).try(:other_description) %>
      <%= @project.scope.datum.try(:data_description) %>

      <% if @project.scope.try(:datum).try(:confidential) == true %>
      Your confidential or commercially sensitive data will be protected with a standard Non-Disclosure Agreement, the form of which is here
    </div>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I test the projects show page, with a form that answers the scope question as true (so that data is required to show), nothing is displayed. The google inspector doesn't recognise the data partial view.

In rails console, I tried:

```
 SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 25
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Project id: 25, title: "asdf ", description: "this is the overview", video_proposal: true, link_to_video_proposal: "IMG_0034.MOV", draft: false, expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest: "2015-05-10 00:00:00", slug: nil, created_at: "2015-04-10 04:53:05", updated_at: "2015-04-10 04:54:37", hero_image: "IMG_1631.JPG", motivation: "asdf asdf", approach: "asdf asdf", results: "asdf adfasdf ", completion_date: "2015-09-10", start_date: "2015-06-10", courses_id: nil, video_id: nil, recurring_project: true, frequency: "true", date_of_student_invitation: nil, date_for_student_interest: "2015-05-10", closed: false, student_id: nil, creator_id: 1, educator_id: nil, project_question_id: nil, project_answer_id: nil, published_date: nil, student_objective: "sdaf safasdf", industry_relevance: "asdf asdfaf", report: true, standard_licence: false, bespoke_licence: false, bespoke_licence_form: "", research_consulting: false, other_outcome: "0", industry_id: 7, limited_disclosure: nil, disclose: true>]> 
2.1.1p76 :013 > 

2.1.1p76 :008 > Scope.where(project_id: 25)
  Scope Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "scopes".* FROM "scopes" WHERE "scopes"."project_id" = 25
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Scope id: 6, created_at: "2015-04-10 07:40:04", updated_at: "2015-04-10 07:40:04", if_datum: false, if_material: false, if_mentoring: false, if_participant: false, if_funding: false, if_ethic: true, if_group_research: false, project_id: 25, program_id: nil, proposal_id: nil>]> 

2.1.1p76 :005 > puts Project.scope.try(:data).inspect
```

The result I get to this query is: 
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/base.rb:70:in `scope'
        from (irb):5
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in`start'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in`'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in`'

However, if I try:

```
2.1.1p76 :010 > puts Scope.try(:datum).inspect
nil
 => nil
```

Taryn's suggestion:

```
2.1.1p76 :013 > project = Project.find(25)
  Project Load (34.8ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
 => #<Project id: 25, title: "asdf ", description: "this is the overview", video_proposal: true, link_to_video_proposal: "IMG_0034.MOV", draft: false, expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest: "2015-05-10 00:00:00", slug: nil, created_at: "2015-04-10 04:53:05", updated_at: "2015-04-10 04:54:37", hero_image: "IMG_1631.JPG", motivation: "asdf asdf", approach: "asdf asdf", results: "asdf adfasdf ", completion_date: "2015-09-10", start_date: "2015-06-10", courses_id: nil, video_id: nil, recurring_project: true, frequency: "true", date_of_student_invitation: nil, date_for_student_interest: "2015-05-10", closed: false, student_id: nil, creator_id: 1, educator_id: nil, project_question_id: nil, project_answer_id: nil, published_date: nil, student_objective: "sdaf safasdf", industry_relevance: "asdf asdfaf", report: true, standard_licence: false, bespoke_licence: false, bespoke_licence_form: "", research_consulting: false, other_outcome: "0", industry_id: 7, limited_disclosure: nil, disclose: true> 
2.1.1p76 :014 > puts project.scope.try(:data)
  Scope Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "scopes".* FROM "scopes" WHERE "scopes"."project_id" = $1 ORDER BY "scopes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 25]]

 => nil
```

Next Steps:

```
2.1.1p76 :015 > puts project.inspect
#<Project id: 25, title: "asdf ", description: "this is the overview", video_proposal: true, link_to_video_proposal: "IMG_0034.MOV", draft: false, expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest: "2015-05-10 00:00:00", slug: nil, created_at: "2015-04-10 04:53:05", updated_at: "2015-04-10 04:54:37", hero_image: "IMG_1631.JPG", motivation: "asdf asdf", approach: "asdf asdf", results: "asdf adfasdf ", completion_date: "2015-09-10", start_date: "2015-06-10", courses_id: nil, video_id: nil, recurring_project: true, frequency: "true", date_of_student_invitation: nil, date_for_student_interest: "2015-05-10", closed: false, student_id: nil, creator_id: 1, educator_id: nil, project_question_id: nil, project_answer_id: nil, published_date: nil, student_objective: "sdaf safasdf", industry_relevance: "asdf asdfaf", report: true, standard_licence: false, bespoke_licence: false, bespoke_licence_form: "", research_consulting: false, other_outcome: "0", industry_id: 7, limited_disclosure: nil, disclose: true>
 => nil 
2.1.1p76 :016 > puts project.scope.inspect
#<Scope id: 6, created_at: "2015-04-10 07:40:04", updated_at: "2015-04-10 07:40:04", if_datum: false, if_material: false, if_mentoring: false, if_participant: false, if_funding: false, if_ethic: true, if_group_research: false, project_id: 25, program_id: nil, proposal_id: nil>
 => nil 
2.1.1p76 :017 > puts project.scope.try(:data).inspect
nil
 => nil
```

Projects table has:

```
t.string   "title"

    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "video_proposal"
    t.string   "link_to_video_proposal"
    t.boolean  "draft",                            default: true
    t.datetime "expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "hero_image"
    t.text     "motivation"
    t.text     "approach"
    t.text     "results"
    t.date     "completion_date"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.integer  "courses_id"
    t.string   "video_id"
    t.boolean  "recurring_project",                default: true
    t.string   "frequency"
    t.date     "date_of_student_invitation"
    t.date     "date_for_student_interest"
    t.boolean  "closed",                           default: false
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "creator_id"
    t.integer  "educator_id"
    t.integer  "project_question_id"
    t.integer  "project_answer_id"
    t.date     "published_date"
    t.text     "student_objective"
    t.text     "industry_relevance"
    t.boolean  "report"
    t.boolean  "standard_licence"
    t.boolean  "bespoke_licence"
    t.string   "bespoke_licence_form"
    t.boolean  "research_consulting"
    t.text     "other_outcome"
    t.integer  "industry_id"
    t.string   "limited_disclosure"
    t.boolean  "disclose",                         default: true
```

Scopes table has:

```
t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "if_datum",          default: false
    t.boolean  "if_material",       default: false
    t.boolean  "if_mentoring",      default: false
    t.boolean  "if_participant",    default: false
    t.boolean  "if_funding",        default: false
    t.boolean  "if_ethic",          default: true
    t.boolean  "if_group_research", default: false
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.integer  "program_id"
    t.integer  "proposal_id"
```

Datum model:

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :scope

end
```

Scope model:

```
class Scope < ActiveRecord::Base


belongs_to :project

has_one :datum 

accepts_nested_attributes_for :datum


end
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so... your code says definitively that a scope `has_one datum`. it does not have `data` - that method doesn't exist and never will (unless you set that up). so, for any given scope, you can only ever use `datum` - that's all there is available. that's what you should use. if you want different behaviour - you need to change your setup

So this is valid code:

```
project.scope.datum
```

this is not:

```
project.scope.data
```

this will always return false (actually nil)

```
project.scope.try(:data)
```

this one has a hope of returning something other than nil:

```
project.scope.try(:datum)
```

you probably don't actually mean what you're trying here:

```
@project.scope.try(:data) == true
```

The above will not work ever. Firstly, `data` does not exist on the `scope` class. only `datum` exists - because that's what you wrote in your class. Secondly... the way that Rails works is to set up an actual instance of class `Datum` when you call `scope.datum` - it won't ever equal `true`... it will either exist or not... ie it will either be present or not.

if the intent behind the above code is "if there is one datum for this scope... then do X" then you should probably write the conditional like this:

```
@project.scope.datum.present?
```

Comment: Thanks Taryn, but reason that it has one datum is that datum is singular for data.

Comment: When I try: <% if @project.scope.datum == true %>
            <%= render 'data/particulars'%>
        <% end %>

Comment: No, reason why i's datum is that you have written `has_one :datum` ... if you want data, then you must instead write `has_many :data`

Comment: I'll try the @project.scope.datum.present? suggestion

Comment: Yes, that's because datum is never 'true' it's an actual instance of class `Data`... and you must use `present?` on it instead of testing if it equals `true`

Comment: I recommend reading up a bit more on Rails. these rails guides are extremely useful and will give you a much better grounding in how all this stuff actually works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Thanks very much. I have them and I refer to them often, but I find it difficult to read them into the context of my issues. I think there is a layer of assumed knowledge that is required to read them (as is my problem with each of the other texts I have read for rails). I keep going back to them though. Thanks very much again.

Comment: Yep, assumed knowledge is fair - you probably need a base-level in `ruby` itself... and it might be worth looking for a book or online resource for that? there are some things that aren't well described about when to use things like `project` vs `@project` that keep cropping up for newbies that i speak with... but that's basic rails... there's a lot of keep on top of :P